# Remove Page Name From Wordpress Menu

Tags: menus, pages

I have a Wordpress menu that are both being used as a normal menu with page name that links to the page. I want to echo the same registered menu, but without the page name. To be clear, I still want the anchorlink, but I do not want any text contained within the anchorlink.

```
<li><a href="the-page-link"></a></li>
```

The reason I want this is because I style the anchorlinks as small circles.

Is this possible? I tried to clear the content in css, but that does not affect the anchorlink when the page name is echoed in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could use the jQuery empty() function like this to remove the text inside the anchorlink,

```
$('nav > ul > li > a').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with pure CSS like so:

```
nav > ul > li > a { text-indent:-9999px; outline:none; }
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS "text-indent:-9999px;" sometimes jQuery is loaded slowly and you can see the menu name and after a second it will disappear. With CSS you'll not have such a problem.